# Project hosting vs. my own SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, project-management

I'm working on different projects with some small teams (2-3 people for each).

Those projects are about some scientific stuff, most (probably all) the code will be released under GPL after the publication of some results and we don't want to spend money for this.

My first question is: should i keep my local SVN server or you know some good service for this?

Both of them have some disadvantages and services like xp-dev.com looks pretty interesting but should i trust them? [i'll get only the free plan]

Online services give you some tools for project management, what do you think about them?

UPDATE: code shouldn't be visible to !teammates until it will be released

Comment: Just make it visible to everyone anyway. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

for svn check out Assembla - https://www.assembla.com/plans

scroll down to the 'Free Repositories' / 'Free Public Workspaces'

---

or switch to git and use GitHub?

http://github.com/plans - Open source is free

---

running your own server seems like extra work to me? backup, admin, etc...

Comment: yes my own server is an extra work but i want to keep the source closed until the public release

Comment: Github now supports SVN reading and writing. Github++

Comment: The assembla 'Free Repositories' option appears to be both free and private - offering git or svn - 2 GB limit, seems to fit the bill

Comment: yes, that's cool.
do you use it? uptime? is it safe?

Comment: yes, I have been using paid version for about 2 years; never had any issues, before that I used free version for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

How about having two repositories,  One for unpublished code where rights can be managed. I've used [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/), it is free and I had no complaints.  Once the source is ready, simply synchronise with your public repository, on CodePlex for example and check in.

The entire process can be automated and made part of your build script which can be hosted in something like TeamCity or simply kicked off with a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Google Code](http://code.google.com/), which provides Subversion and Mercurial as source control options. It's great for open source stuff. Microsoft has started their own hosting called [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) which looks promising.

As long as you're working on open source software, you shouldn't need to pay for hosting, there are plenty of free project hosts available.

Online services are great, you don't need to worry about managing a machine to serve the central repository and it's quickly and easily available to others via links, clean interfaces and ~100% uptime.

Comment: I second the vote for google code. It may be slightly less featureful than bitbucket, but the simplicity is a blessing in many cases. It has exactly the right number of features.

Comment: ok but i want to keep the source private until i decide to release it.
We want a private repo while we're writing code :)

Comment: I never understand the desire to keep code secret until it magically stops sucking. Just put it all public, all the way, what's the difference? Not to mention it's version controlled, we'll know all your dark dirty secrets when it's made public.

Comment: The code is a by-product of his research, he doesn't want to make his findings public until his research has been officially published.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Beanstalk](http://www.beanstalkapp.com/) personally, and I absolutely love it. It does deployments, and web hooks, so you can integrate it with whatever tools you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm next to Unfuddle, it's very elegant and simple. Saves tons of time to keep the team in sync. Invaluable service.

Answer (score 0):

After few months and some experiments, I completed my first project using assembla.com (free svn plan) and everything was perfect.